# How updates are handled for commercial applications?

Tags: software-center, application-development, commercial

I'm planning on publishing a commercial (paid) application to Software Center and I've seen that during the process of submiting the app I have to upload a .deb package. I'd like to know if there is any way to submit updates to my certain application once it is already in Software Center. As far as I know apps from the Software Center are all in a ppa and that's how they get the updates, but in my case, there would be no ppa (correct me if I'm wrong)

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't upload a .deb package, you upload a source package, which can be built
in to a .deb package.

This is then put in a PPA to build the .deb packages that users will install.

Therefore there is a PPA behind the scenes.

You can then submit updates to your application by uploading an updated
source package at a later date. This will then be reviewed and go through
QA before being made available to users.

I look forward to seeing your application in the Software Center.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One last question, what about the source code, does it get published or not?

Comment: @QQQ that would be a great follow up question, just ask another one in another post (so we have a nice FAQ for this sort of thing).

Comment: Posted a question here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/68658/what-happens-with-the-source-code-when-submitting-an-application